# How to move modern SharePoint Online pages with all their contents/elements?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pages, move, modern

I'm using the method in the link below to move some modern SharePoint Online pages from one site collection to another. However, when the pages move most of the contents/elements are stripped from the pages (i.e. pictures, coloring, etc.). Can anything be added to the script I'm using in the link to make sure it moves the pages with all their contents/elements?

https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2019/06/16/how-to-migrate-content-with-pnp-provisioning-engine/?fbclid=IwAR0Z0oPOEABdb27nwGEb_i7EuUO9BSBawlm5UlQMX_zpCvcaFZbXgucKU3g

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.You could use [mover](https://mover.io/connectors/sharepoint/) or [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/sharepoint-migration?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIusS8vNPT6QIVTGoqCh3lAAIREAAYASAAEgLIdvD_BwE) to move SharePoint Online pages from one site collection to another.

2.You also could get a PnP template from an existing page and provision a page.

[How to create a SharePoint Modern page using PnP provision template in Power Automate (Microsoft Flow), Azure Logic Apps, or PowerApps](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-modern-page-pnp-template.html)